# Require help in Inserting records from one table to another table in Sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005, insertion

I have two tables. One is temp table and another is main table.
In temp table, I have a column called "Contract Number" which is of "float" datatype.
In Main table, I have a same column "Contract Number" but with "varchar(50)" datatype.

In Temp table, the Contract Number column has a value "**40494318**".
When I insert into the Main table the value changes into "**4.04943e+007**".

I used the query,

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Contract (Contract_Num)  
Select Contract_Num From Main_Contract
```

Please help me how to insert the values correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're sure Contract_Num is always an integer:

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Contract
    (Contract_Num)
    SELECT CAST(Contract_Num AS INT)
        FROM Main_Contract
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to cast it as a varchar

```
INSERT INTO Temp_Contract (Contract_Num)
    Select cast(cast(cast(Contract_Num as float) as int) as nvarchar(50))
     From  Main_Contract
```

Comment: This explicit cast is the same as the implicit cast already being done. You'll still get the same `4.04943e+007` result.

Comment: No need to try it. Yours is essentially the same as mine now.